# Find minimum of the piecewise affine function

Tags: derivatives, optimization, differential

I am trying to analytically calculate minimum (function is convex, thus minimum) of a piecewise affine function:

$f(x) = max\{ a_1^Tx+b, \dots, a_n^Tx+b \}$

The only possible solution I see here is to plot the function and read it from plot, I am unable to cope doing it analytically. Could somebody give me a hint how could be done?

Comment: Maybe using the formula $\forall a,b\in\Bbb R,\;\max(a,b) = \dfrac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$.

Comment: The optimum is the intersection of some two lines but you may have a hard time figuring out which one. It is easy to solve numerically though.